# How to fix"NameError: name 'load_model' is not defined"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, pycharm

I am reading the book"Deep Learning with Python" and I have come across a problem. I have used Pycharm to save models in anther file and when I tried to load it by the function 'load_model()', the system supports that 'NameError: name 'load_model' is not defined'. pycharm 2019.1.3 keras 2.2.4 tensorflow 1.13.0

```
from keras import models
model = load_model('cats_and_dogs_small_2.h5')
```

Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/python program/visualizDemo/main.py", line 2, in 
    model = load_model('cats_and_dogs_small_2.h5')
NameError: name 'load_model' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @krain I think you probably missed the specification of `custom_object` like loss function, metric function, etc, when you **save** your model. I had the same issue before and the resolution is simply to add what I said in my`model.save()`.

Answer (score 13):

What you are missing here is, load_model function is inside models class so you have to reference models class.

```
from keras import models    
model = models.load_model('filename.h5')
```

In order to do it your way, you have to use import as following

```
from keras.models import load_model
```

PS: This next line might help you in future. If you are trying to load weights, use function:

```
model.load_weight('weights_file.h5')
```